# Creating new team column in the SharePoint list using Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I want to create a new term column using Graph API, I followed these documentations

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/columndefinition?view=graph-rest-1.0

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/termcolumn?view=graph-rest-1.0

**URL**

POST [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/columns](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/%7Bsite-id%7D/lists/%7Blist-id%7D/columns)

**Body**

```
{
    "description": "test2",
    "enforceUniqueValues": false,
    "hidden": false,
    "indexed": false,
    "name": "test2",
    "term": {
        "allowMultipleValues": true,
        "termSet": {
            "id": "f6ad7041-6336-4b8e-b449-444441d69753"
        },
        "showFullyQualifiedName": false
    }
}
```

**Response**

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "invalidRequest",
        "message": "Invalid request",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2021-10-25T11:06:20",
            "request-id": "13c4f443-8495-4fd8-a939-6b037a2193dd",
            "client-request-id": "13c4f443-8495-4fd8-a939-6b037a2193dd"
        }
    }
}
```

Please help me to resolve this issue

[Postman Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXtlf.png)

Comment: Is this a standard termSet or custom one that you have created? My recommendation is that create the same column from SharePoint UI and then get the column Definition using Graph API and replicate the same in the new column.

Comment: Hi @DeepakSharma 

Thanks for your comment, I wanted to create Managed metadata column, the new column definition is different from the column definition return from Graph API